# Get ratios with time shift in Google Cloud Monitoring

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm running a query which compares data to that from 7 days previously.  The query only shows if there is a difference.  It doesn't reflect if the difference is an increase or a decrease.

What I'm looking for is a centre 0 line with a line graph showing if the current data is an increase or a decrease on last week's data, (ideally) as a percentage.

```
fetch generic_node
| metric 'custom.googleapis.com/myCustomMetric'
| group_by 4h, [row_count: row_count()]
| {value [v_now: val()] ; time_shift 1w}
| join | div
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change the last table operation to `sub`:

```
fetch generic_node
| metric 'custom.googleapis.com/myCustomMetric'
| group_by 4h, [row_count: row_count()]
| {value [v_now: val()] ; time_shift 1w}
| join | sub
```

Note that after the `join` table operation, you get a time series table with two value columns - the first column for current data and the second for last week's data. A following arithmetic function(textual name for an arithmetic operator) acts as a table operation shortcut for generating a single value column by performing that arithmetic function on the two value columns.

`div` here means

```
| value div(val(0), val(1))
```

That's why you get a ratio. And `sub` means

```
| value sub(val(0), val(1))
```

where you can get the difference.

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference?hl=en#div-func
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference?hl=en#sub-func

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
fetch generic_node
| metric 'custom.googleapis.com/myCustomMetric'
| group_by [], [row_count: row_count()]
| {value [v_now: val()] ; time_shift 1w}
| join | div
```

Or

```
fetch generic_node
| metric 'custom.googleapis.com/myCustomMetric'
| group_by [], mean(val())
| {
    ident
  ;
    time_shift 1w
  }
| join | div
```

Docs:

- https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/examples#qlx-ratio-ratio
- https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/examples#qlx-union-over-time

Comment: Your first query returns a result very similar to what I already have.  The `mean` query simply returns a solid 1.  What I'm looking for is a +/- graph which shows an increade/decrease.  I'm beginning to wonder if this is indicated by the value being <1/>1